# In Android where i have to add a code for restarting a background service?

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, android-alarms

I am confused to add a code for alarm manager to start a service in Android. Where do I have to add code for the alarm manager? What permission do I have to ask in manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

These permissions are required

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>   
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
```

Comment: why have to maintain the seperate process for reciever??